# Hide table columns in php

Tags: php, html-table, hide, rows

I want to hide table rows with a id, for Example:
If the user requests this address: http://***.com/index.php?show=1,3
Information is displayed only in columns 1 and 3 but not 2.

```
<table>
 <tr>
    <td> 1 </td>
    <td> hidden </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td> 2 </td>
    <td> shown </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td> 3 </td>
    <td> shown </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: That's nice. Good luck with that. Did you have a question?

Comment: this is my question peleas answer me If you know

Comment: I don't see a third column at all in your markup

Comment: You're not asking a question. You've stating a list of requirements. We're here to help, not do your job for you.

Comment: Basically you have to hide second column in this case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your ids in the table is dynamic then you can do this.

```
$temp=explode(',',$_GET['show']);
<?php if(in_array('1',$temp) { ?>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td> something</td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Just change '1' to your dynamic variable.

Comment: If you are sending value through url just encode it then send it will be secure then now.

Comment: He asked to hide the whole rows. This will hide only the content of the cell.

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
<?php
$show = explode(',', $_GET[show]);
?>
<table>
<?php if (in_array(1, $show)) { ?>
<tr>
    <td> 1 </td>
    <td> hidden </td>
</tr>

<?php }?>
...
```

If you have many rows you can use e.g. for cycle.